# Three-point function general form

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, correlation-functions, ward-identity

The general matrix element of the electromagnetic current can be written as $$iM^ {\mu} = \left< p^\prime,s^\prime | j^\mu (x) | p,s\right>=\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime)\left( R(q^2) \gamma^{\mu} + S(q^2) (p^{\prime \mu} + p^{\mu}) + P(q^2) (p^{\prime \mu} - p^{\mu})  + G(q^2) i \sigma^{\mu \nu } (p_{ \nu}^{\prime} + p_{\nu}) \right)u(p,s)$$ with $q=p^{\prime}-p$ and $R,S,P,G$ are arbitrary functions of momentum transfer. With the Ward identity it can be shown that $P$ and $G$ must be zero. But how can someone show that $G,P$ have to be zero with equations of motions and the conservation of electromagnetic current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime) i \sigma^{\mu \nu}(p^\prime+p)_\nu u(p,s)=-\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime) q^\mu u(p,s),$ the form factor decomposition can be rewritten as $$\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime) \left[ R(q^2) \gamma^\mu +S(q^2) (p^\prime+p)^\mu+\tilde{P}(q^2)q^\mu        \right]u(p,s)  $$ with $\tilde{P}(q^2):=P(q^2)-G(q^2)$. Finally current conservation, expressed by $M^\mu q_\mu=0$, leads to $\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime)\tilde{P}(q^2) q^2u(p,s)=0$, where the relations $p\!\!\!/  u(p,s)=m u(p,s)$, $\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime) p^\prime \! \!\!\!\! /=m\bar{u}(p^\prime,s^\prime)$ and $p^2=p^{\prime 2}=m^2$ where used.

Edit: Charge conservation, expressed by $\partial_\mu j^\mu(x)=0$, implies $0=  \langle p^\prime ,s |\partial_\mu j^\mu(x)|p,s\rangle $ $=\partial_\mu \langle p^\prime, s^\prime | j^\mu(x)|p,s\rangle$ $= \partial_\mu \langle p^\prime,s^\prime|e^{iP\cdot x}j^\mu(0)e^{-iP\cdot x}|p,s\rangle$ $=\partial_\mu\langle p^\prime,s^\prime|e^{ip^\prime\cdot x}j^\mu(0)e^{-ip\cdot x}|p,s\rangle$ $=i(p^\prime-p)_\mu \langle p^\prime,s^\prime|j^\mu(0)|p,s\rangle e^{i(p^\prime-p)\cdot x}=i q_\mu\bar{u}(p^\prime, s^\prime)[R(q^2) \gamma^\mu+\ldots]u(p,s) e^{i(p^\prime-p)\cdot x}$

Comment: $q_\mu M^{\mu}=0$ is the Ward identity or not? And what does Ward identity have to do with charge conservation?

Comment: The Ward identy is a consequence of the continuity equation $\partial_\mu j^\mu(x)=0$. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: And what is the justification for $\left< p^\prime,s^\prime | \partial_{\mu}j^\mu (x) | p,s\right>=\partial_{\mu} \left< p^\prime,s^\prime | j^\mu (x) | p,s\right>$?

Comment: Obviously $\langle a | j(x+h)-j(x)|b\rangle =\langle a |j(x+h)|b\rangle -\langle a| j(x) |b\rangle$...